# Windows app to trim the commentary at the end of a song

Tags: windows, audio, audio-editing

Is there a windows app to trim commentary at the end of a song?
Like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVXziMFEqX0
The music ends at circa 3:42, then there's silence for at least 10 seconds, and commentary.
I want to batch trim all my aac/opus files from such commentary (and the silence of course).
Format support doesn't really matter, I'll convert them to mp3 anyways.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a single program that does this for you I have a combination that can do it for you. The combination is:

- [Python](https://www.python.org/) - *Programming Language* Download and install from https://www.python.org/downloads/ selecting Python 3.6 or later and selecting "Add to Path" during the install.
- [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) - *Numeric Library* Once you have installed Python you can install from the command prompt with `pip install numpy`
- [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) - *Video Editing in Python* Once you have installed Python you can install from the command prompt with `pip install moviepy`
- [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) - *Media Processing Tools* Automatically downloaded and installed by MoviePy on first use.

*Note that this process was inspired by [this blog post](https://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/07/04/automatic-soccer-highlights-compilations-with-python/) which automatically clips the highlights of football matches based on the average audio levels.*

You can then put together a python script something like the following:

```
import os  # Pythons default library for OS operations
import glob  # Pythons default library for file pattern matching
import numpy as np # for numerical operations
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip

def find_silences(audio):
    """ Find the silences in an audio clip """
    cut = lambda i: audio.subclip(i,i+1).to_soundarray(fps=22000)  # get one sec of audio as an array
    volume = lambda array: np.sqrt(((1.0*array)**2).mean())  # RMS of Array
    # Use the above to get a list of the volumes per second
    volumes = [volume(cut(i)) for i in range(0,int(sound.duration-1))] 
    # Get the times when the volume is zero
    zero_secs = [i for i, v in enumerate(volumes) if v == 0.0]

def process_file(fname):
    """ Process a file """
    audio = AudioFileClip(filename=files[0])
    silences = find_silences(audio)
    two_secs = [s for s, i in silences[:-1] if s+1 == silences[i+1]]
    if len(two_secs) == 0:
        print(fname, "no two second silence found!")
    else:  # We have at least one 2 sec silence
        clipped = audio.subclip(0, two_secs[0])  # Clip to that length
        clipped.to_audiofile('temp.mp3')  # Save to a temp name
        os.rename(fname, fname+".orig")  # keep the old just in case
        os.rename('temp.mp3', fname)   # rename temp to original name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for FNAME in glob.glob("*.mp3"):  # All the MP3 files in the current directory
        process_file(FNAME)
```

Note that the above code is very rough & ready but should get you started.